# Deleting 1 or more rows from Named Range using Multiselect userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am not very familiar with coding. I found this piece of code online and it works to remove the rows from my spreadsheet that I select in the userform, but it breaks the named range every time and will not work again. The code I am using is

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DelRng As Range
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1    ' no more need to loop backwards
        If Me.ListBox3.Selected(i) = True Then
            If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = sh.Range("A" & i + 2 & ":F" & i + 2)
            Else
                Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, sh.Range("A" & i + 2 & ":F" & i + 2))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete    ' delete chosen rows (if any)
    
    ListBox3.ListIndex = ListBox3.ListIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

The formula for the named range is `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,2)`.

Can anyone help me with code that will work repeatedly?

Comment: Do you *need* to use a named range?

Comment: Not necessarily.  I found some code that showed using a named range to populate the listbox in the user form.  I basically want to be able to use the form to add, delete and update the information in the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely getting the point.
Your Code works fine. 
What kind of error do you get? How does your named Range gets broken
If you delete rows of a named range, the range get's smaller.
Maybe redefining this range helps. To do so just delete it and redefine it.
If you don't know the commands the makro-recorder might help you.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names("Named_Range").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="Named_Range", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1:R10C3"
```

This defines a Range from Row1-Column1 To Row10-Column3

Please give us some more information.
Best regards

Comment: This is the formula for the named range =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,6)
After I run the code I submitted to delete 1 or more rows, I get this error message
Run-time error ‘380’:
Could not set the RowSource Property. Invalid Property value.
When I go back and look at the formula for the named range it is
=OFFSET(Sheet1!#REF!,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,6)